# Jquery-- Cascading Dropdown Not binding values?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, cascadingdropdown

Hi iam using Cascading Dropdown using Jquery in asp.net

My webMethod is getting called, iam getting result but values are not getting bind.

here is my code

```
    if ($(".ddlService").val() != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "Port.aspx/VCode_Get",
                    data: "{ServiceID:'" + $(".ddlService").val() + "'}",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (html) {
                        try {                           
                            Success(html);
                        } catch (ex) {
                            alert("ErrCode:7");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert("ErrCode:8");
                    }
                })
                return false;
            }
            else {
                    $(".ddlVoyage").empty();
                    $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option value=''>Select </option>");
                }
        });
    });

    function Success(result) {
       alert("SUccess Called");
       $(".ddlVoyage").empty();
       $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option  value=''>Select </option>");

       $.each(data, function (index, result) {
           $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option value='" + result.VoyageMasterID + "'>" + result.VoyageCode + "</option>");

        });          
    }
```

iam getting the alert

> **alert("SUccess Called");**

ALso to the targent Dropdown iam getting value Select  bind to it, but values are not getting bind

Iam having values in my Database too..,

I think something need to be changed in this 2 lines where iam struck

```
  $.each(data, function (index, result) {
           $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option value='" + result.VoyageMasterID + "'>" + result.VoyageCode + "</option>");
```

Iam not getting idea of how to bind those values to Select , Im struck here, Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think your are binding the html in wrong way..

```
 ..<option value='" + result.VoyageMasterID + "'>"...
                  //--^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^---here looks like you have a response as JSON..
```

try this

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        ...
        dataType: "json",  //here get response as json
        .....  
       });
```

and make sure you send the response as JSON in your controller (which i think you are already doin it).. changing the dataType as JSON should work..

**updated**

your json

```
 { "Table": [ { "VoyageMasterID": 3, "VoyageCode": "9101" }, { "VoyageMasterID": 3, "VoyageCode": "9101" }]}
```

try this

```
function Success(result) {
   alert("SUccess Called");
   $(".ddlVoyage").empty();
   $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option  value=''>Select </option>");

   $.each(result.Table, function (index, value) {
       $(".ddlVoyage").append("<option value='" + value.VoyageMasterID + "'>" + value.VoyageCode + "</option>");

    });          
 }
```

since you json is in array of objects.. you  have to loop through result.Table(your object's name is table) and get its correspoding voyagemasterid and voyagecode

Comment: Lot of Difference with small change, As i have changed to Json iam Not getting Error , as well as iam getting data bind but as " Undefined" Not exact values

Comment: ok ... undefined.. because you result json doesnot content `result.VoyageMasterID`.. please check your response in console and can you show me yourJSON structure

Comment: this is my Json Result { "Table": [ { "VoyageMasterID": 3, "VoyageCode": "9101" }, { "VoyageMasterID": 3, "VoyageCode": "9101" }]}

Comment: iam getting result when i give it as result.d

Comment: Sorry iam not getting data bind. Iam getting resuult in alert when i give as result.d but here its not working.., I think iam very near but Small prob

Comment: did you try out with replacing the function with mine ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".ddlVoyage").append("<option value='" + value.Value + "'>" + value.Text + "</option>");
```

This is how i use it

```
 $('#offices').change(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("FillDepartments", "Contact")',
                type: 'POST',
                cache: false,
                data: { id: $(this).val() },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (departments) {
                    $.each(departments, function (i, departments) {
                        $("#departments").append('<option value=' + departments.Value + '>' + departments.Text + '</option>')
                    });
                },

                error: function (error) {
                    alert(errorss);
                }
            });
        });
```